# CalendarView не реагирует на xml разметку

Tags: android, xml, calendar

CalendarView не реагирует на xml разметку. Кроме background ничего не работает.

```
 <CalendarView
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:background="@color/colorBackground"
 android:selectedWeekBackgroundColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark">
```

Цвета colorBackground и colorPrimaryDark существенно отличаются и не заметить разницы невозможно.
Так же не реагирует на

```
android:focusedMonthDateColor="@color/colorBackgroundDark"
android:shownWeekCount="5"
```

и другие свойства...
Тестирую на реальном устройстве API 22 ANDROID 5.1

И да вот еще... Как поменять способ отображения (что бы только один месяц был виден а не два с половиной)
насчет увеличения шрифта думал... но опять же НЕ РЕАГИРУЕТ

[image: Скриншот]

Answer (score 1):

Для начала оберните `CalendarView` в `LinearLayout`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<CalendarView
    android:id="@+id/calendarView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:selectedWeekBackgroundColor="#ff0000"
    android:weekNumberColor="#0000ff"
    android:weekSeparatorLineColor="#00ff00" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Дату можно отслеживать через метод `setOnDateChangeListener()`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    CalendarView calendarView = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
    calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year,
                                        int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            int mYear = year;
            int mMonth = month;
            int mDay = dayOfMonth;
            String selectedDate = new StringBuilder().append(mMonth + 1)
                    .append("-").append(mDay).append("-").append(mYear)
                    .append(" ").toString();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), selectedDate, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: но он и так в LinearLayout...